# PHP Zend XML-RPC - Any way to disable the 'nil' in requests?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc, xml-nil

I'm using Zend XML-RPC Client library to send XML requests to another non-PHP XML RPC server.(it's a java JBoss install, but I don't have control to change it/patch it/hack it). One request I'm making has a `<nil/>` element, which is a XML-RPC extension. The XML-RPC server I'm talking to doesn't support that because the request fails with `Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Unknown type: nil`.

Is there any way to tell Zend to not send the `<nil/>` value and send something else instead? Others have asked this before: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, however:

```
The array of parameters for the remote method can contain native PHP types, 
Zend_XmlRpc_Value objects, or a mix of each.
```

You actually have full control over the type of parameters passed to the remote method. Converting *null* values to empty strings before sending the request should be trivial, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in the end I put an empty array and changed my XML RPC spec